# keep duplicates by key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries, and I would like to obtain those that have the same value in a key:

```
my_list_of_dicts = [{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 6,
    'name': 'Mariah'
  },{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Louis'
  }
]
```

I want to keep those items that have the same 'name', so, I would like to obtain something like:

```
duplicates: [{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Peter'
  }, {
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'John'
  }
]
```

I'm trying (not successfully):

```
duplicates = [item for item in my_list_of_dicts if len(my_list_of_dicts.get('name', None)) > 1]
```

I have clear my problem with this code, but not able to do the right sentence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another concise way using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list_of_dicts = [{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 6,
    'name': 'Mariah'
  },{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Louis'
  }
]

c = Counter(x['name'] for x in my_list_of_dicts)

duplicates = [x for x in my_list_of_dicts if c[x['name']] > 1]
```

Comment: This provides an `O(N)` solution in contrast to the `O(N^2)` approach in the OP. Very nice!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following list comprehension:

```
>>> [d for d in my_list_of_dicts if len([e for e in my_list_of_dicts if e['name'] == d['name']]) > 1]
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'John'},
 {'id': 5, 'name': 'Peter'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Peter'},
 {'id': 7, 'name': 'John'}]
```

Comment: O(N^2) time complexity needlessly

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list_of_dicts = [{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 6,
    'name': 'Mariah'
  },{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Louis'
  }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_of_dicts)
df[df.name.isin(df[df.name.duplicated()]['name'])].to_json(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt similar to @cucuru
Hopefully Helpful.
Explained in comments what I did differently.

```
my_list_of_dicts = [{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Peter'
  },{
    'id': 6,
    'name': 'Mariah'
  },{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'John'
  },{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Louis'
  }
]


# Create a list of names
names = [person.get('name') for person in my_list_of_dicts]

# Add item to list if the name occurs more than once in names
duplicates = [item for item in my_list_of_dicts if names.count(item.get('name')) > 1]

print(duplicates)
```

produces

```
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'John'}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'Peter'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Peter'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'John'}]

[Program finished]
```